# Build.gradle startup failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was working with my project, but my notebook froze for a long time. So, I rebooted it and ran Android Studio, but the project doesn't work. All the activities and classes are ok, but Android Studio shows mt build.gradle error. And my build.gradle(app) file became empty! There is nothing in this file! I don't know, whats's the problem. Here's the message from Android Studio

```
Error:(1, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\dns\MyApplication\app\build.gradle': 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 1.
```

And this:

```
Load Settings
        Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\dns\MyApplication\.idea\misc.xml': Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        Please correct the file content
```

What do I need to do know? Maybe, I need to find these files? 
I did not change anything in them.

Thank you for help!

Here's my gradle file:

```
Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. buildscript { repositories { jcenter() } dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong // in the individual module build.gradle files } } allprojects { repositories { jcenter() } } task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }
```

Comment: please share you build.gradle

Comment: This is it // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the file. Anyways, you have an unexpected character at line 1, column 1, or the very first character in your file is invalid.

Comment: I guess you use Windows 10, this also happens with me. You should fix you build.gradle, it could be corrupted after your notebook froze. And try to delete `.idea` then reimport your project.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio "file" menu choose "Invalidate Caches/ Restart"