# Gradle 'xxxx' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to open project of my colleague, but it shows error in settings.gradle file. how can I fix this error?
here is the message from Android Studio

[image: .]

Comment: paste your gradle file

Comment: specifically your `settings.gradle` file

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38379994/5241603

Comment: where is your settins.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

it seems your settings.gradle is wrong.
settings.gradle should like this:

```
include ':app'
```

> the include statement indicates that the app subdirectory is the only
>   additional subproject.if you add an android library project,it too
>   will be added to this file.